# PCH was compiled with module cache path Issue

Tags: swift, xcode, core-foundation, pch

My project is running perfectly before i just relocate my project in Document folder.
After that it shows me

**Showing Recent Messages**
**PCH was compiled with module cache path** **'/Users/dr195/Desktop/audiofitness/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/13I86ZOMWRD8V', but the path is currently '/Users/dr195/Documents/Shubham Saini Current/audiofitness/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/13I86ZOMWRD8V'**

**Could not build module 'Darwin'**

**Could not build module 'Core Foundation'**

I have tried by deleting derive data folder from the xcode setting. But issue is same nothing changes.
Anyone Please let me know how to get rid from this problem

Answer (score 1):

do one thing quit Xcode and open terminal after that navigate to your project directory and then write an code to remove the module cache in your project and the open your project and clean it and build.

Comment: Bro, I have already deleted the derive data folder. So i think that module cache is already removed by deleting derive data folder.

Comment: just create an backup for your project and try to do it again.  may be in some chance it would work .

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same thing with a Swift Package Project. In that case: delete the hidden `.build` folder inside your project folder. Afterwards build again and it should build fresh without problems.